# Expression for Adding Computed column in DataTable with a percentage sign

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datatable, calculated-columns

I've a `DataTable` with a column `VatRate` retrieved from database column of `float` `DataType`. Now I want to add a computed `DataColumn` in my `DataTable` with VatRate formated to two decimal places and a `%` sign followed by a space.

So if value in `VatRate` column is `12.5` then the value in `ComputedColumn` should be `12.50 %`.

**NOTE:**
I want it on DisplayMember of Combobox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably be easier to just bind that column to a e.g. DataGrid, and then define **on the grid** that this particular column should display with a fixed format, e.g. `##0.00 %`.

In general: don't try to "force" your data to look like it should - try to define **display properties** on the UI for that!

The data is just the data - don't harass it with display options - those belong into the UI and not into your data.

**Update:**

In ASP.NET, the [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) e.g. has a property called `DataTextFormatString` which allows you to define a separate display format for your data.

The Winforms [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class also has a property called `FormatString` that allows you to define how the data should look like.

**Update #2:** you're using Winforms - so set your `FormatString` on the combobox to:

```
this.comboBox1.FormatString = "#0.00 %";
```

and then fill in values like `0.0875, 0.125` and so forth - they'll be displayed as `8.75 %` and `12.50 %` respectively.

Comment: I want it on DisplayMember of Combobox

Comment: @ismail: winforms? asp.net? WPF?

Comment: winforms. Sorry! added winform tag now.

Comment: `vatRatesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VatRateWithPercent", typeof(string), "Convert(VatRate, 'System.String') + ' %'"));` worked. But I want VatRate in two decimal places. Any Idea???

Comment: Or even if you can give me FormatString

Comment: Why does it multiply it with hundred? I already have proper values in DB

Comment: @Ismail: you need to have percentage data; 0.08 = 8% - that's because you have the "%" in your FormatString - it interprets the data as percentage.

Answer (score 3):

If formatting would not be an issue, you could have used an expression like this:

```
myDataColumn.Expression="Convert(VatRate, 'System.String') + '%'"
```

But why you need additional columns?
Can't you simply assing a format string to the binding used to show the data in your From/Window/Page, or use a ToString(...) when writing in some stream?

Comment: Thanks, `vatRatesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VatRateWithPercent", typeof(string), "Convert(VatRate, 'System.String') + ' %'"));` worked. But I want VatRate in two decimal places. Any Idea???

Comment: Did you read post/comments about binding and/or formatting? You should format your data in presentation, not storing (even if just in memory like with data table). If you still want format in column's expression, you can use "Len" and "Substring" functions to get the right formula, but you will need multiple instances of Convert(..., ...) and you will get an extremely long expression. I think this isn't the best way, and you have to format your data only in presentation step.